# Apache wrong RewriteRule for WebDAV service

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, webdav

I have an issue with a RewriteRule that works (more or less) in html-view with a browser but not as WebDav-service with a client (davfs or cadaver under linux). My feeling is that it is related to the RewriteRule.

What I want to do: From the URL-perspective: Have a folder /users/*somebody*, where *somebody* is the individual username. And I want to have a shortcut /private, which points directly to the /users/*myusername* directory where I have write access to.
In the filesystem I have /storage/davroot for the DAV and DocumentRoot and /storage/davusers for all the user-directories. Notice that the user-dirs are not inside the DocumentRoot which makes it a bit tricky.

My current solution is this:

```
    # It's NOT working with the RewriteCond -- why?
    # RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} ^[a-z].*
    RewriteRule ^\/private(.*)$ /users/%{LA-U:REMOTE_USER}$1 [PT]

   <Directory /storage/davroot/>
            # some settings for the rights, do not care
   </Directory>
   Alias /users /storage/davusers/
   <Directory "/storage/davusers/">
            # some other settings for the rights, also don't care
   </Directory>
```

What is correct: Almost the whole browser-view is correct. Except one issue: The url /private/ is correctly listed, the url bar stays /private/ (wanted behaviour). But the url /private gets translated to /users/username/ and also the url bar changes to this address. Why?

If I login with a webdav client (davfs) the topic even gets stranger. The private folder is empty, the users folder inaccessible. With cadaver the private folder is inaccessible and the users folder is correctly displayed.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bad idea. Rewriting often works fine for 'dumb' HTTP endpoints such as files, but for WebDAV this changes.

The problem is that WebDAV HTTP requests such as `PROPFIND` return results that contain urls. These urls must match whatever url you used to access the resource.

Apache's rewriting only works on incoming requests. It doesn't 'live modify' the outgoing xml responses to match whatever came in.

The sane thing to do in cases such as this, is to not rewrite, but just redirect. Not every client might support that, but at least your server works in a sane predictable way, and according to spec.

Another possibility is to use something like `AliasMatch`, because this directive actually does stuff with the local path, and not just the url. If you can get it to work, I imagine that mod_webdav will continue to behave in a sane way.

But I'm not sure if `AliasMatch` can use headers like `REMOTE_USER`.